# TexShop Statistics (Word Count) with BasicTeX

Tags: mactex, texshop, word-count

I recently re-installed tex on my mac, and decided to go with the BasicTeX package rather than the full (2.4GB) MacTeX package, together with the MacTeX-additions package, which includes TexShop.  (Running TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2014) and TexShop 3.39).

After downloading the various packages I use, everything is running smoothly, *except* for the "statistics" functionality that provides a word count (under the menu Edit>Statistics...). After typesetting, if I call up the statistics it just displays '0' in all the fields, even if I click the "Update" button.

My guess is that there is some tool (texcount, perhaps?) which is included in the full installation but not BasicTex.  Is there any relatively straightforward way to get the "statistics" functionality working, or do I need to just bite the bullet and install the full MacTex package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the (older) copy of TeXShop source I have here, it uses `detex` to do this, and it's not installed in my copy of BasicTeX. You can install the detex packages using TeX Live Utility by switching to the "Packages" tab and searching for detex in the list. Right-click on detex and choose "Install Selected Packages" from the contextual menu (or use the corresponding item from the Actions menu).