# tlmgr open documentation for <package>. BasicTeX

Tags: packages, documentation

I know it's convenient to install packages with `tlmgr install <package>`, but I couldn't find a way to open the documentation of the respective package; I know it installs them, I can manually go to the folder where they're installed (which is also not easy to find).

So what's the best alternative to do something similar to `tlmgr docs <package>`?

**Edit**: I'm using BasicTeX.

Comment: `texdoc <package>` should work too.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer It's not installed in my PC. I'm using BasicTeX.

Comment: If you want a minimal installation, there are also texdoc online, and CTAN.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is supposed to be a comment, but I do not have enough reputation to do
that.

I think [this script](https://gist.github.com/kadrach/6228314) may help. It
says (I changed it a little bit):

1. Install `texdoc` by

   ```
   tlmgr install texdoc
   ```
2. Enable automatic build of documentation, which is disabled (by default)
   for BasicTeX `tlmgr`:

   ```
   tlmgr option docfiles 1
   ```
3. Build documentation for all installed packages:

   ```
   tlmgr install --reinstall $(tlmgr list --only-installed | sed -E 's/i (.*):.*$/\1/')
   ```

   The `tlmgr list` format is `i <pkg-name>: <description>` so we get
   the name with `sed`. I used ERE (Extended Regular Expression) since
   BasicTeX is only available on OS X, where ERE is available with `-E`.
   Note that `tlmgr list --only-installed` and
   `tlmgr info --only-installed` seems to be the same, checked with [Bash
   process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution) and `diff`.

In some of the steps above you may need `sudo` (depending on how you
installed BasicTeX). Use it wisely. [This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/249868/) is related, I
think.

Answer (score 5):

You need to install texdoc on BasicTeX with `tlmgr install texdoc` in order to be able to run `texdoc <package>`.