# tlgmr error: First directive needs to be 'name'…

Tags: pandoc, tlmgr, macos, texdoc

I asked this question on stackoverflow first ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537955/tlgmr-error-first-directive-needs-to-be-name)), buy asking her too.

I am getting the following error on various `tlmgr` related commands, such as:

```
| => tlmgr list
First directive needs to be 'name', not ros/xetex/generic/tibetan at /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 104, <TMP> line 21169.

| => tlmgr install --reinstall $(tlmgr list --only-installed | sed -E 's/i (.*):.*$/\1/')
First directive needs to be 'name', not ros/xetex/generic/tibetan at /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 104, <TMP> line 21169.
First directive needs to be 'name', not ros/xetex/generic/tibetan at /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 104, <TMP> line 21169.

| => tlmgr install uow
First directive needs to be 'name', not ros/xetex/generic/tibetan at /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 104, <TMP> line 21169.
```

I'm not sure what has happened or what to do. My latex environment is installed via `BasicTex`, and the following info may be relevant:

```
| => sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.14.6
BuildVersion:   18G103
basictex: 2019.1011
TeX 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2019)
kpathsea version 6.3.1
```

I am still able to compile documents, directly or via `pandoc`.

I'm not sure if there is any other info that my be relevant. I did make some changes to the behaviour of `tlmgr` to accommodate the `texdoc` package as outlined in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/304202).

Any help is greatly appreciated—thanks in advance.

Atanas.

Comment: tlmgr was broken for a day yesterday, `tlmgr update --self` should get things back in sync but your mirror of ctan may not see the fixed update yet.

Comment: https://tug.org/pipermail/tex-live/2019-December/044616.html

Comment: Thanks @DavidCarlisle… It doen's seem to work, still getting the same error as (`First directive needs to be 'name', not ros/xetex/generic/tibetan at /usr/local/texlive/2019basic/tlpkg/TeXLive/TLPOBJ.pm line 104, <TMP> line 21169.`). I have set it it to three different mirrors from the [CTAN list](https://www.ctan.org/mirrors) using four different mirrors. I used the following example command: `tlmgr -repository http://mirror.aarnet.edu.au/CTAN/systems/texlive/tlnet update --self`. Any ideas?